# Register OCX at Current User Registry

Tags: vb6, registry, activex

Is it possible to register OCX or dll at current user registry programmatically in VB 6.0? I have searched a lot but could not found any solution. I have found the code of registration at local machine level but could not find any help at current user level, following is the link which contain the code of registering dll at local machine.

http://www.trixar.com/~makai/regx.htm

Kindly give me some direction so that I can register my controls only for current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the DLL registers itself is down to the DLL and it's authors, the calling application has no direct control over this.

If it's for a single specific DLL, you can try and create the registry entries yourself but you will need to know exactly which objects, interfaces, and typelibs need to be registered and their details. (This is not something I'd do myself except for the simplest DLL written by me)

Answer (score 4):

The VB6 compiler emits self-registration code according to the standards for COM self-registration, which implies per-machine level registration.

This is a packaging and deployment issue, not a programming issue.

As the documentation for Windows Installer suggests, self-registration is considered a fallback mechanism.  Most of the time your installation process should be registering such a library itself instead of calling the self-reg entrypoint.  This offers several benefits including the possibility of doing per-user registration during a per-user install.

But beginning with Windows XP a new option became available.  You can install applications as isolated without component registration, a technique also described as "registration free COM."  This allows applications to be installed without registering the components at any level as well as allowing different applications to use their own private copies of most non-system component libraries they need.  The exception is out-of-process servers, which always need per-machine registration.

So look for a tool designed to assist in reg-free COM packaging.  There are a few open source products for use by VB6 developers, some more generalized commercial tools, and some Microsoft manifest tools which require more manual configuration but are supposed to be useful for this.

Comment: I second the RegFree com approach. It took me quite some time to become comfortable with, but on the long run it saves a lot of headaches. I use Side by Side Manifestmaker from http://www.mazecomputer.com/sxsv2.htm

Comment: I'd love to see somebody write a solid article on doing this using Microsoft's tools from the Windows SDK as well.  So far the things I have read contained a lot of hand waving and no working examples.